# Check if a model is confirmable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm kinda new to Rails, so if I am doing this totally wrong, just tell me :)

I have two models built with devise in my rails app, one is confirmable, the other is not.

I would like to set the `after_sign_up_path_for(resource)` on the user home page or on a separated page indicating that a confirmation email has been sent depending on wether my resource has to confirm its registration or not.

- I can check existence of the confirm fields in the data model, but is there a cleaner way to do it, something like `resource.confirmable?`
- Is there a cleaner way than overwriting `after_sign_up_path` to redirect to different pages depending on wether the model is confirmable ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
resource.class.devise_modules.include?(:confirmable)
```

Or

```
resource.respond_to?(:confirmed?)
```

Regarding to check if the user is already confirmed, you could use the following:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  if resource.class.devise_modules.include?(:confirmable) 
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      "path for confirmed user"
    else
      "path for waiting for confirmation"
    end
  else
    "path for non confirmable model"
  end
end
```

Check out the docs: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Confirmable

Comment: that seems to fit, thanks ! I'll wait a few hours before marking it as resolved so I can have answers on "is this good to override after_sign_up_path method".

Comment: @Logar added some more info in case you need it

Comment: Well that's perfect, I guess I have my answer !